# Pandas Rolling With MultiIndex and GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at creating a rolling sum of the **past** `n` results for a given `id`. The index of the DataFrame is the `id` and `date`.

The code below works for non-time-based rolling windows, i.e. integers. However, does not work for time-based intervals, such as `'10D'` (10 days).

1.

```py
df2['rolling_sum'] = df2.groupby(['id'])['a_column_to_rolling_sum'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).sum().shift())

>> Rolling Result
id               date_dt   
-2143487296      2019-07-08         NaN
                 2019-07-15    0.104478
                 2019-07-19    0.217260
-2143477291      2019-07-05         NaN
                 2019-07-10    0.238764
                 2019-07-16    0.391669
                 2019-07-22    0.255469
                 2019-07-29    0.244011
```

The code below is able to almost get what I want, however, when a new group is reached, it should be `NaN` as there cannot be a previous sum.

2.

```py
rolling_result = (
    df2
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .groupby('id')['a_column_to_rolling_sum']
    .rolling('10D', min_periods=1)
    .sum()
    .shift(1)
)

# Add to df
df2['rolling_sum'] = rolling_result

>> Rolling Result
id               date_dt   
-2143487296      2019-07-08         NaN
                 2019-07-15    0.104478
                 2019-07-19    0.217260
-2143477291      2019-07-05    0.229506  <- Why is it not NaN!
                 2019-07-10    0.238764
                 2019-07-16    0.391669
                 2019-07-22    0.255469
                 2019-07-29    0.244011
```

[Image of the two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDCSk.png) where the left is what I want and the right is what I get from *2*.

To recap: I want to group by multiple columns, including an `id` and `date`. For each of these groups, I want to create a rolling sum of the **previous** `n` days (`'10D'`) and `m` occurrences (integer value), such that the start of each group is `NaN`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `min_periods=1` argument from `rolling` and this will give you what you seek (for reference, the `min_periods` argument is documented as "Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value; otherwise, result is np.nan.")

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, this does not yield the correct result. For a window that is specified by an offset, it defaults to 1 anyway. I want NaN on the first occurrence, as there should be no sum of previous `n`.

Comment: did you try explicitly setting `min_periods=None`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring during the shift. The rolling result needs to be grouped again, i.e.

```py
rolling_result = (
    df2
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .groupby('id')['a_column_to_rolling_sum']
    .rolling('10D', min_periods=1)
    .sum()
    .groupby('id')
    .shift(1)
)

# Add to df
df2['rolling_sum'] = rolling_result
```

This works with multiple `groupby` arguments too. If you have other indices, remove all bar the date, i.e., `.reset_index(level=(0,1,...))`.